# Symbian java - is it possible to develop symbian using java

Tags: java-me, symbian

Is it possible for me to develop symbian applications using java? Or is it only c++ that is supported by symbian? if I can which sdk do I download and do I use netbeans or eclipse(indigo)?

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed develop in Java on Symbian devices (Java ME) either in Eclipse or Netbeans. Relevant SDKs are [here](http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/ec866fab-4b76-49f6-b5a5-af0631419e9c/S60_All_in_One_SDKs.html), and dev documentation [here](http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-660EC670-B7DB-4005-BF2D-411E5C0B3867_cover.html).